# How to write custom comparator in java?

Tags: java, comparator, treemap

I want to store key-value pairs in `TreeMap` and sort the entries based on the value of key as per the following logic:

1. "type" (case insensitive) key should be at first.
2. the key start with "metadata" (case insensitive) should be at last in ascending order
3. rest of the keys(case insensitive) should be in middle in ascending order

I am using Java 8 version.

Program:

```
public class CustomeCamarator  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomComparator comparator = new CustomComparator();
        Map<String,Object> empData=new TreeMap<>(comparator);
        empData.put("name","someName");
        empData.put("DOB","someDOB");
        empData.put("address","someAddress");
        empData.put("type","employee data");
        empData.put("ContactNo.","someContactNumber");
        empData.put("metadata.source","someMetaDataSource");
        empData.put("metadata.location","someMetaDataLocation");
        empData.put("metadata","someMetaData");
        System.out.println(empData);
        System.out.println(empData.containsKey("metadata"));//should be true but showing false
    }
}
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String str1 = o1.toLowerCase();
        String str2 = o2.toLowerCase();
        if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {
            return -1;
        }else if(!str1.contains("metadata") && !str2.contains("metadata")) {
            return str1.compareTo(str2);
        }else if(o1.contains("metadata") && !o2.contains("metadata")) {
            return 1;
        }else if(!o1.contains("metadata") && o2.contains("metadata")) {
            return -1;
        }else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}





**Expected Output like this:**
type: someType
address: someAddress
ContactNo: someContactNumber
DOB: someDOB
name: someName
metadata: someMetaData
metadata.location: someMetaDataLocation
metadata.source: someMetaDataSource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following covers your cases

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  @Override public int compare(String left, String right) {
    left = left.toLowerCase();
    right = right.toLowerCase();
    final int LEFT = -1;
    final int RIGHT = 1;
    // exact match!
    if (left.equals(right)) return 0;
    // not identical, so consider 'type' match
    if ("type".equals(left)) return LEFT;
    if ("type".equals(right)) return RIGHT;
    // at this point we know neither matches 'type' so lets check for 'metadata' prefix
    if (left.startsWith("metadata")) {
      // if both start with metadata use natural ordering
      if (right.startsWith("metadata")) return left.compareTo(right);
      // only left starts with 'metadata' so right comes first
      else return RIGHT;
    }
    // only right starts with 'metadata' so left comes first
    if (right.startsWith("metadata")) return LEFT;
    // at this point we know they are not equal but neither contains 'text' nor starts with 'metadata' so use natural ordering
    return left.compareTo(right);
  }
}
```

Comment: The first lines of your `compare` method, `final left = left.toLowerCase(); final right = right.toLowerCase();` are not valid syntax. For a variable declaration, they would need a type, but there are already variables with that name. For an assignment, the `final` modifier is inappropriate. Besides that, potentially creating new strings with lowercase versions, for the sake of a case insensitive comparison that might already stop at the first character, is very inefficient and not even correct for all characters and locales.

Comment: You can implement the same logic as simple as `Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator .comparing((String s) -> !"type".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) .thenComparing(s -> s.regionMatches(true, 0, "metadata", 0, 8)) .thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);` which is not only simpler but avoids creating new strings during the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a comparator that implements that logic to the `TreeMap` constructor:

```
Map<String, Integer> order = Map.of(
    "type", Integer.MIN_VALUE, 
    "metadata", Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Map<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<>(
    Comparator.comparing(a -> order.getOrDefault(
        a.toLowerCase().startsWith("metadata") ?
            "metadata" :
            a.toLowerCase(), 
        0))
    .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

I think this should do it. The idea is to use a map to first compare by some `Integer` value. The value corresponding to `type` is `Integer`'s min value, so that it always comes first. The value for `metadata` is `Integer`'s max value, so that it always comes last. Before searching in the map, we first check if the string starts with `metadata`. It it does, we just change it to `metadata`, to obtain the `Integer` value from the map. If there is no entry in the map, we return `0`. It there's a tie, we use `String`'s natural order.

---

**EDIT:**
If you are on Java8 and cannot use `Map.of`, consider using a traditional `HashMap` instead:

```
Map<String, Integer> order = new HashMap<>();
order.put("type", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
order.put("metadata", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Thank You @fps for your response but we are using JAVA 8 and Map.of is introduced in JAVA 9.

Comment: @VinayakKanade Added a java8 compatible version

Answer (score 0):

I used a [Decision Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table) as follows

```
type  metadata.*  others
2     1           0

Key 1    Key 2    Result    Action
  0        0        0       String.compare
  0        1        1       return -1
  0        2        2       return 1
  1        0        3       return 1
  1        1        4       String.compare
  1        2        5       return 1
  2        0        6       return -1
  2        1        7       return -1
  2        2        8       return 0
```

*Key 1* and *Key 2* are the parameters to method [compare()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) of interface `Comparator`. Each key can have one of three values:

1. type
2. [starts with] metadata
3. none of the above

Here is the implementation:

```java
Comparator<String> comparator = (k1, k2) -> {
    Objects.requireNonNull(k1);
    Objects.requireNonNull(k2);
    int k1Val;
    int k2Val;
    if (k1.equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {
        k1Val = 2;
    }
    else if (k1.matches("(?i)^metadata.*$")) {
        k1Val = 1;
    }
    else {
        k1Val = 0;
    }
    if (k2.equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {
        k2Val = 2;
    }
    else if (k2.matches("(?i)^metadata.*$")) {
        k2Val = 1;
    }
    else {
        k2Val = 0;
    }
    int retVal;
    int index = k1Val * 3 + k2Val;
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        case 4:
            retVal = k1.compareToIgnoreCase(k2);
            break;
        case 1:
        case 6:
        case 7:
            retVal = -1;
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 5:
            retVal = 1;
            break;
        case 8:
            retVal = 0;
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled: " + index);
    }
    return retVal;
};
Map<String, Object> empData = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
empData.put("name","someName");
empData.put("address","someAddress");
empData.put("type","employee data");
empData.put("ContactNo.","someContactNumber");
empData.put("Metadata.source","someMetaDataSource");
empData.put("metadata.location","someMetaDataLocation");
empData.put("metadata","someMetaData");
System.out.println(empData);
```

Output from running above code.

```
{type=employee data, address=someAddress, ContactNo.=someContactNumber, name=someName, metadata=someMetaData, metadata.location=someMetaDataLocation, Metadata.source=someMetaDataSource}
```

Answer (score -1):

[`TreeMap` supports a custom `Comparator` in its constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-). Just implement the `Comparator` interface and pass it to the constructor.

Comment: I think that @VinayakKanade is asking for the actual implementation. The question title states: _How to write custom comparator in java_

Comment: @Abra He's not showing any attempt to use a Comparator in his code.

Comment: Added my attempt